# Does AWS S3 GetObject provide random access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can [provide HTTP Range headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#API_GetObject_RequestSyntax) to AWS S3's GetObject to request a specified range of bytes of an object.

Is it truly random access, or does S3 have to process all of the object before that range before returning my requested range?

Is the range header simply reducing the bytes transferred, or does it also provide efficient random access?

Comment: Why do you ask? Are you concerned about performance? It is likely that your Internet bandwidth will impose more of a restriction than the ability for S3 to seek to a particular location. I would recommend you perform a few tests — retrieve content towards the end of a large object and see whether you detect any performance impact.

Comment: Yes, performance concerns. I've got a binary search based algorithm that will perform well with random access, and I wanted to know if using s3 would prevent me from using it. I'll run some tests to verify if needed. I was hoping this was known knowledge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did a quick test with a 2GB file in S3 and executed [ranged gets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/use-byte-range-fetches.html) for 8 bytes at various offsets in the file (including start, middle, and end). The total time seemed to be pretty consistent at 250ms user time (including starting node.js, loading packages, executing range GetObject), as measured by `time` from my Mac to us-east-1.

I wasn't able to find a definitive statement in the AWS documentation for the expected behavior here though I'd hope and expect that it is close to O(1) constant time.

I'd encourage you to investigate further before committing to a design. And maybe update us here.

[Update] Here are the results of a slightly more extensive experiment (thanks very much to @VivekMaharajh). S3, Lambda, a 2GB file, and 100 reads of 100 bytes to random parts of the file:

[image]

Comment: My reason for doing lambda was that I figured the latency would be orders of magnitude better than what you were seeing (from your machine) since the lambda is executing in the same datacenter as the s3. I didn't see that much of a reduction tho...

Comment: @VivekMaharajh excellent contribution to the answer, thank you.