# Partition csv data in s3 bucket for querying using Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have csv log data coming every hour in a single s3 bucket and I want to partition it for improving queries performance as well as converting it to parquet.

Also how can I add partitions automatically for new logs that will be added.

Note :

1. csv file names follow standard date format
2. files are written from external source and cannot be edited to be written in folders but only in the main bucket
3. I wanted to convert csv files to parquet separately

Comment: How are the CSV files being created? Can that creation process put them in an appropriately-named folder? Do you wish to convert each individual file into Parquet, or group them together after some time interval? Feel free to edit your question to add such details.

Comment: Did you consider using [AWS DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) for these queries ? The S3 is good for holding the full log entry, but what you want to query should be in the DB (NoSQL for better performance). And based on how your `.csv`'s look like and also what kind of query you build, you can think of optimizations. It used to be required for S3 to be partition by ensuring random access by ensuring the prefix is a hash (e.g. SHA, MD5, or any function that can produce a random prefix for your case), I don't think that's the case since 2018.

Comment: more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176997/does-aws-s3-getobject-provide-random-access

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your situation is:

- Objects are being uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket
- You would like those objects to be placed in a path hierarchy to support Amazon Athena partitioning

You could configure an **Amazon S3 event** to trigger an **AWS Lambda function** whenever a new object is created.

The Lambda function would:

- Read the filename (or the contents of the file) to determine where it should be placed in the hierarchy
- Perform a `CopyObject()` to put the object in the correct location (S3 does not have a 'move' command)
- Delete the original object with `DeleteObject()`

Be careful that the above operation does not result in an event that triggers the Lambda function again (eg do it in a different folder or bucket), otherwise an infinite loop would occur.

When you wish to **convert the CSV files to Parquet**, see:

- [Converting to Columnar Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html)
- [Using AWS Athena To Convert A CSV File To Parquet | CloudForecast Blog](https://www.cloudforecast.io/blog/Athena-to-transform-CSV-to-Parquet/)